# How bad is it if water is leaking through concrete in the lower parking levels of my apartment building?

Tags: civil-engineering, concrete, waterproofing

I live in a 14 story apartment complex built in the 70s that has three underground parking levels.

Today it looks like there's water leaking through cracks in the concrete on the second and third levels of the parking garage in multiple places throughout (not just one concrete block affected).

Is this a I-should-have-left-as-soon-as-it-happened-why-are-you-posting-about-it-online-and-not-runnning situation? Or is this a problem 2-3 years down the line? I told security about it, and I think management knows as they shut the water off for about an hour today. How bad is this if it goes on for more than a day?

I'm hoping it's fine if they fix it shortly, but if I shouldn't worry now, at what point should I worry? If this isn't fixed in a week? Or a month? Or if it does get fixed, should I worry if it happens again in another month?

Thanks so much for your help!

[image: Leak 1 center right]

[image: Leak 2 constant leaking at concrete edge]

[image: Leak 3 over cars]

[image: Leak 4, notice the large puddling occurring]

Comment: you should be talking to the building inspector in your area, not to a bunch of strangers on the internet

Comment: For reinforced concrete structures, generally the problem is when moisture persists for a long time, such as years. Then negative effects like carbonation to concrete and corrosion to rebar occur. The longer the moist condition, the worse damage (beware that you say the building is old though). A 2 days water leak just by itself would generally do no damage. But of course, do not rely on information you get here on internet. You should have someone competent look at it on site. Other than fixing the leak source immediately, you should also seek direction from local building department asap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pipe or connection to an appliance has cracked and needs to be repaired. Even a defective toilet can leak a lot of water.

Concrete structures can likely take the leak without too much damage. But the source of the leak must be located urgently and fixed. After that, the structure needs to be inspected for any damage, mold, or fissures!

Building departments and insurance companies accept certificates from companies that are licensed and specialize in leak detection and water damage repair!